# Using href without initial slash when linking to files

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with linking images and links from HTML file to another HTML file .

The only way I have to link links or images is this way:

- from one html to another:

  ```
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Logotype</a>
  ```
- of a photo:

  ```
  <img src="/photos/mouse.png" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block mt-5" alt="about us">
  ```

My question was how do I not use the forward slash on all the links. I am a student and my teacher is forcing me to remove that slash from all links. And if I remove it, it doesn't work, nor does the link to the CSS work.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to properly use this site.

Comment: Then, please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/

Comment: I think your teacher meant to make you remove the first occurrence of "/".

Comment: I don't see why your teacher would force you to remove slashes, it makes no sense

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the folder structure. You can always use relative paths to refer to other files (i.e., begin with `../` or `./`).

Comment: I'm going to try to put "../" instead of "/". because if my teacher does not like the code I am disapproved. Above, the page I made was perfect, even verified with validator.w3.org and it's perfect, but that's the way the teachers are in Argentina, if they don't like what they see they disapprove of you.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the photos in **same folder**. Then you would not need to give / before the file name.

Like this:

```
<img src='myphoto.jpg'/>
```